# Excel row is overridden when writing the test results using parallel execution

Tags: java, test-reporting

I'm able to write the test results back into Excel when I execute using multi-threaded execution. But at times, some rows are getting overwritten. This is cause the Excel report not showing few test results.

Below is the `@afterMethod` that I used to write the results to excel sheet after every method is executed.

Please let me know how we can avoid results getting overwritten on same row while doing parallel execution.

```
public void excelreport() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(outfilelocation);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    sheet = wb.getSheet(WorksheetName);

    lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int i = lastRowNum + 1; // first row is column header, so starting from row 2
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
    
    XSSFCell testcase = row.createCell(0);
    XSSFCell results = row.createCell(1);
    
    testcase.setCellValue("Test case name");
    results.setCellValue("Pass/fail");
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outfilelocation));
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you may be reinventing the wheel. Can't your test runner write test reports, maybe in cvs, which you can import in Excel?

Comment: Data gets overwritten in your code when multiple threads open the file at the same time, change data, then write: whoever writes last, wins. This is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You can avoid it by either having all tests report to a central location / program, where you can synchronize and prevent them from overwriting each other's results, or by having them write to different files which you later merge.